# Show that $f$ is a bivariate density

Tags: probability-theory

Let $g$ be a continuous univariate density, and let $f(x,y)=2g(x)g(y)$ for $x\leq y$ and $f(x,y)=0$ if $x>y$. Show that $f$ is a bivariate density.

For some reason, nothing I attempt makes any sense.The $2g(y)$ is throwing me off.

Does this mean that $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(x,y) dxdy=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}g(x)dx*2\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}g(y)dy=1$$when $x\leq y$ and $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(x,y) dxdy=0$$ if $x>y$. I'm not seeing how this can be used to show that $f$ is a bivariate density. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please make precise the bounds of your integral, the symbols $\int^\infty$ and $\int_{-\infty}$ do not exist (and add proper infinitesimals $dxdy$).

Comment: Edits have been made. Thank you.

Comment: Now, your "Does this mean" would be correct if one was given $f(x,y)=2g(x)g(y)$ *for every* $(x,y)$. But here $f(x,y)=0$ when $x\gt y$. Can you modify your try?

Comment: Try attempt edited.

Comment: Ah? So some number (the result of the double integral) is 0 **and** 1 at the same time? Hmmm...

Comment: I'm not following you. I don't see where the double integral can be 0 and 1 at the same time. Could you please recommend a strategy for me to use? This is literally my last homework exercise of my graduate program. I am eager to get this completed.

Comment: This is what you wrote: $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(x,y) dxdy=1$ and $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(x,y) dxdy=0$.

Comment: Even with the conditions provided?